# What is the similarity values of Li Wordnet-based measure

Tags: html-lists, similarity, wordnet, measure

I have confusion of the similarity value of the Li measure. I read in paper that the values in (0,1) so Is it varies between 0 and 1? or it has only two values either 0 or 1.

Comment: Since that's a similarity value, I'm almost sure that (0, 1) is a value range. A binary similarity measure would be a really poor identifier! However, providing a link to that article would be useful (we don't know the publication's title either...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Lin Similarity? It scales between 0 and 1 and is computed as following (citing the [NLTK documentation](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html)):

> Lin Similarity: Return a score
>   denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the Information
>   Content (IC) of the Least Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor
>   node) and that of the two input Synsets. The relationship is given by
>   the equation 2 * IC(lcs) / (IC(s1) + IC(s2)).
>
> ```
> >>> dog.lin_similarity(cat, semcor_ic)
> 0.88632886280862277
> ```

You can find a comparison between different word similarity measurements in [this paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/N/N04/N04-3012.pdf). It explains the Lin Similarity as follows:

> The lin and jcn measures augment the information content of the LCS
>   with the sum of the information content of concepts A and B
>   themselves. The lin measure scales the information content of the LCS
>   by this sum, while jcn takes the difference of this sum and the
>   information content of the LCS.